# WordPress Ajax Load More Not Displaying

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, alm

I have been struggling with this problem for the last two weeks now, and the problem is that I am not able to display the ajax load more (and any of its post and even the button) on my custom archive page. I want to provide a sleek archive for my visitors, allowing them to just scroll in previous posts without having to use any pagination. And the strange thing is, when I echo the shortcode for the ajax load more, it doesn't display at all. When I inspect the code, it has been automatically set to visibility:hidden. What really seems to be the problem here?

How can I display this in my "page-arkiv.php"?

Plugin used: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Code:

```
<h1>TEST PAGE </h1>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more]'); ?>
```

Output:

```
<div id="ajax-load-more" class="ajax-load-more-wrap default" data-alm-id="" data-canonical-url="http://whatever.com/arkiv/" data-slug="arkiv" data-post-id="73">
<div class="alm-listing alm-ajax" data-repeater="default" data-post-type="post" data-order="DESC" data-orderby="date" data-offset="0" data-posts-per-page="5" data-scroll="true" data-scroll-distance="100" data-max-pages="0" data-pause-override="false" data-pause="false" data-button-label="Older Posts" data-transition="fade" data-images-loaded="false">
</div>
<div class="alm-btn-wrap" style="visibility: hidden;"><button class="alm-load-more-btn more " rel="next">Older Posts</button></div></div>
```

And this is my Reading settings:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the shortcode and plugin that you’re using please?

Comment: @Noah Now I have provided more information, hopefully enough to get some help. If not, please let me know if you want me to include more (if necessary).

Comment: Thanks @askaale How many posts do you have? If you have less than five, it probably isn’t displaying because the default posts per page is five.

Comment: @Noah Unfortunately I have a total of six posts, and none seem to show.

Comment: Are they all published and are they actually the *post* post type? Or are the a custom post type?

Comment: Also, are you comfortable giving a link to your site?

Comment: It's not a custom post type, just the regular post. And also, I could send you it in a direct message, but I would prefer not to share it to the public. Is that okay?

Comment: Could someone please help me with this issue?